# Switch case with multiple values

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

Is there something like array of case statement and put it as single case statement into switch- suppose

```
String[] statements={"height","HEIGHT"};
```

and then

```
switch(code){
 case statements: 
  //code here
  break;
 case something_else:
  break;
}
```

so if we add values into String array then it will automatically matched from that array in switch? like

```
  var1||var2||whatever //accessed from array or anything else for matching
```

is there any implementation similar like this?

Comment: you can try `String.toUpperCase()` before feeding into the `Switch`

Comment: Consider to replace the arrays and switch statement with enums.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove the break to get OR

```
switch(code){
 case case1:   
 case case2:
    doSomething();
  break;
}
```

Comment: What if am reading that array of values from Database or it's values are generated while runtime

Answer (score 2):

I think I wouldn't youse a switch in this case.
I would do probably something like this

```
if(Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourValue)){
   //do something
}else{
   //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

Unless you can boil your data down to one of these, that's all you can use. You can always break out what you would have in the statement array, but you wouldn't be able to make switch dynamic using an array.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements and expressions (available since Java SE 14) don't support matching values from an array. For such cases, the construct you are looking for is a chain of `if`, `else if`, and `else`. You can use `Stream` to easily check if an array contains a given element.

```java
private boolean contains(String[] array, String value) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(value::equals);
}
```

```java
if (contains(statements, code)) {
    // do something with a code
} else if(contains(otherStatements, code)) {
    // do something with another code
} else {
    // do something with other codes
}
```

Answer (score -1):

switch case statements don't break unless you specifically ask it to.

Hence for your case, you can use this as a work around,

```
switch(code){
 case "height":
 case "HEIGHT": 
 case "weight":
  //code here
  break;
 case something_else:
  break;
}
```

Comment: Here you have your cases decoupled from your array. i don't think this is desirable here.